# Evaluate parameters before function uses them

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, series-expansion, coefficients

I want to construct a power series:

```
LP[s_] := With[{x = 1, R = 10, n = 1},
Sum[cc[i + n, n, x, R] s^i, {i, 0, 20}]]
```

but it kinda takes a long time to compute the coefficients cc[...] although they depend on very quickly evaluated parameters b[...] (even for large i, n within 1s)

```
LoI[n_] := Array[k, n]
IB[r_, x_, R_] := {r, x, R}
cc[l_, n_, x_, R_] := 
Sum[Product[b[i, n, x, R]/i!, {i, LoI[n]}] 
KroneckerDelta[l, Sum[j, {j, LoI[n]}]], 
Evaluate[ Apply[Sequence, (IB[#, 0, l] & /@ LoI[n])]]]
```

where

```
b[l_, n_, x_, R_] := 
With[{a = 0.000001, m = 1}, 
NIntegrate[4 Pi r^2  m(a n r Cos[r/R])^l, {r, x, R}]]
```

and V[] is an elementary function of a single variable so the integral is quickly evaluated.

Can I somehow make Mathematica compute the b[]'s beforehand and then use them to compute the cc[]'s? Or does it just take a long time because the combinatorics of the multidimensional sum are complicated (theres a multinomial coefficient)?

It seems like the computational costs for cc[l,n] comes from larger n (small n and large l also goes very easily) so maybe its more about the combinatorics in the sum.

Does this function constantly re-evaluate the b[]'s and waste time?

Comment: Depends on the full definitions of your code probably. You should really include those definitions, otherwise we cannot run  your code, and if we cannot run your code, we will only be able to provide vague, general suggestions. For instance, if `b` is defined using `SetDelayed` (`:=`), try using `Set` (`=`) instead. That may not always work, *depending on the specifics of the definition of `b`*, but worth a try.

Comment: sure I added this

Comment: Thank you for the additions, but the definitions of `V`and `IB` are still missing, so we cannot yet evaluate your code. If you want to make sure, you can copy your code into a FRESH Mathematica instance (maybe run ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` first, if you don't have any important unsaved results), and see if the code works on its own.

Comment: yeah sorry :) I gave an example V and it shoud compile now